# Preserve Telnet output formatting when displayed in HTML

Tags: html, telnet

I have an output from a telnet connection. Looks similar to this

```
ACTIVE ALARMS REPORT

ID  CATEGORY  DESCRIPTION          ALARM TYPE             DATE    TIME
```

When I save this information to an HTML doc the results look like this:

```
ACTIVE ALARMS REPORT ID CATEGORY DESCRIPTION ALARM TYPE DATE TIME
```

Is there a way to make this code spaced out just how the telnet output is? Is this more of a css question?

The key here is I use python to pull the information from telnet and pass the information to the html doc.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this. You can either pull this data into a table tag. If that is not possible for you, then you can use a pre tag.

Comment: If you see your desired structure inside the HTML code, but it apppears de-structured when opened in a browser, then you probably want to explore wrapping it with the <pre> tag. If the text is already de-structured in the HTML code, then it might be getting formatted by another tool before making it to the final HTML code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your text in `<pre></pre>` tags to preserve formatting such as newlines, tabs, and multiple spaces.